# Multiple axios requests

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm currently working on a project where I'm integrating a checkout page with Klarna. The integration starts with an axios POST request(create order). This POST request gives me a response including an Iframe html_snippet and an order id. After this post request I'm supposed to send a GET request(confirmation page) to Klarna's rest API where the order id from the earlier POST request will be in the GET request's URL. The problem is that I don't know how to chain these requests to be able to use the `response.data.order_id` from the POST request in the GET request URL. This is my code so far. `axios.all()` obviously won't work since the requests are sent at the same time.

```
var axios = require("axios");
const { promiseImpl } = require("ejs");
const { response } = require("express");
 var data = JSON.stringify({
   purchase_country: "SE",
   purchase_currency: "SEK",
   locale: "sv-SE",
   order_amount: 50000,
   order_tax_amount: 4545,
   order_lines: [
     {
       type: "physical",
       reference: "19-402-USA",
       name: "Red T-Shirt",
       quantity: 5,
       quantity_unit: "pcs",
       unit_price: 10000,
       tax_rate: 1000,
       total_amount: 50000,
       total_discount_amount: 0,
       total_tax_amount: 4545,
     },
   ],
   merchant_urls: {
     terms: "https://www.example.com/terms.html",
     checkout: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/checkout",
     confirmation: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/confirmation",
     push: "https://www.example.com/api/push",
   },
 });

 var config = {
   method: "post",
   url: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization:
       "",
   },
   data: data,
 };


 //GET Request (read order)
var axios = require("axios");
var data1 = JSON.stringify({
  purchase_country: "SE",
  purchase_currency: "SEK",
  locale: "sv-SE",
  order_amount: 50000,
  order_tax_amount: 4545,
  order_lines: [
    {
      type: "physical",
      reference: "19-402-USA",
      name: "Red T-Shirt",
      quantity: 5,
      quantity_unit: "pcs",
      unit_price: 10000,
      tax_rate: 1000,
      total_amount: 50000,
      total_discount_amount: 0,
      total_tax_amount: 4545,
    },
  ],
  merchant_urls: {
    terms: "https://www.example.com/terms.html",
    checkout: "https://www.example.com/checkout.html",
    confirmation: "https://www.example.com/confirmation.html",
    push: "https://www.example.com/api/push",
  },
});

var config1 = {
  method: "get",
  url:
    "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/a94f3f40-df22-6334-95d8-eebb2cf8d986",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "",
  },
  data: data1,
};



 var Getrequest = axios(config1);
 var Postrequest = axios(config)

axios.all([
     Postrequest,
     Getrequest
 ])
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response[0].data.order_id)
    app.get("/checkout", function(req, res){
        res.render("checkout.ejs", {datapost: response[0].data.html_snippet})
    })
    app.get("/confirmation", function(req, res){
        res.render("confirmation.ejs", {dataget: response[1].data.html_snippet})
    })


})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the entire code in an `async` function. Then you could do something like:

```js
var Getrequest = await axios(config1);
var Postrequest = await axios(config);

// Do something with the data
```

`await` stops the entire function, so it'll all be in sync.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)